# How to access user data from one application url to another in angular

Tags: angular, session-storage

I want to pass my user data i.e. username, role and other auth details from one parent applications to other applications which we are redirecting from the main app. Is there a way to do it in angular.. the session storage is not accessible in it.

```
sessionStorage.setItem("user", userInfo.email);
sessionStorage.setItem('name', userInfo.given_name);
sessionStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', 'true');
```

I am redirecting the app as below

```
document.location.href = this.Url;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not something you can do with Angular internally.

But,

When you're redirecting the user from one application to another, you can use [query string parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) and parse that query string from the application you're redirected. *Keep in mind that this is not a safe thing to do.*

Instead you may use some kind of hashing mechanism for query string which you'll be validating on the other application's backend that you're redirected.

[JWT Tokens](https://jwt.io/) might help.

So an example flow could be like this:

Before the redirection from app 1, you generate a JWT token with a secret and put values you want to transfer in it. Transfer the jwt token to the app 2 with query string, like `this.url?token={jwtToken}`, let the app 2 parse that query string and pass it to it's backend, validate that jwt token with the secret you provided on app 1, after validating, decode it, return it to the application 2 front end and put decoded values in to its session storage.